# How Do I Export Sharepoint List To Excel Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I want to copy the list of directories in my Documents in Sharepoint but selecting the list on the page and copying and pasting it has been disabled.

The Export to Excel button saves a `query.iqy` file that Excel can open to import the data.

However, I only have Excel online so how do I open this file?

I need to make it accessible for any user in the company to do
i.e. just a button and not having to run a powershell script or use a REST api each time the export is required

Comment: For a while there was an option to export to CSV. But the disabled it. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-or-lists-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9#OfficeVersion=Modern
Maybe the will bring it back someday

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to develop your excel file on a desktop app version of excel, you should be able to use the get data, from file, from SharePoint folder.

The first few clicks after creating that connection show a table of your entire file directory.

Power bi guides are more common than excel guide, but they both use the same power query infrastructure.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Get-Data-quot-From-Folder-quot-from-Sharepoint-Folder/m-p/516393#M241395

If you are looking to import a SharePoint list, however. Check out get data, from online services, from SharePoint list.
They are a specific type of object you can create in SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, as mentioned, I only have Excel online and not the desktop version.